# Custom subsubsection numbering in latex ref

Tags: xetex

Im trying to use an own counter and naming of \subsubsection for custom section names, but it has no affect to \ref.

```
\newcounter{strategyCounter}
\titleformat{\subsubsection} [hang] 
    {\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily} 
    {Strategy\stepcounter{strategyCounter}\thestrategyCounter}
    {1em}{}
...
\subsubsection{Foo}\label{foo}
...
\subsubsection{Bar}\label{bar}
...
see \ref{foo} // output: 1.1.1.1; expected: Strategy 1
see \nameref{foo} // output: Foo; expected: Foo
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're overwriting the usual manner in which `\subsubsection` is handled, the following works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec,hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}% <command>
  [hang]% <shape>
  {\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily}% <format>
  {\thesubsubsection}% <label>
  {1em}% <sep>
  {}% <before-code>

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{Strategy \arabic{subsubsection}}

\newcommand{\strategy}{\subsubsection}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\strategy{Foo}\label{foo}

\strategy{Bar}\label{bar}

See \ref{foo}.% output: Strategy 1

See \nameref{foo}.% output: Foo

\end{document}
```

For semantics, I defined `\strategy` to call `\subsubsection` (so they're basically the same). It provides for more clarity in your code.

Comment: Thank you, all I needed was \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{Strategy \arabic{subsubsection}}